# git clone from->to directory confusion

Tags: git, path, github, directory, git-clone

I'm in my EC2 /var/www directory and want to get the contents my Github repository, htdocs.

When i'm here:

```
/var/www $
```

If I type:

```
git clone git@github.com:tim-peterson/htdocs.git
```

Then Git makes a directory named htdocs inside of /var/www.

However, I just want the contents of my htdocs to be put into the www folder NOT a new folder named /var/www/htdocs.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is https://github.com/tim-peterson/htdocs an existing repository?

Comment: Your problem may be related to not having the public rsa key configured on your EC2 box, check the github getting started docs and see if that helps you along in getting a more meaningful error message.
http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Comment: hi kingcrunch, htdocs is an existing repository, i've added a bunch of stuff to it from a folder on my laptop with the same name

Comment: hi Will, this htdocs is a private repository so I think you are correct in that i probably need to put the key in my EC2 /var/www folder, i'll look it up now but perhaps you advice to hasten that process, i'm really new to git, github and EC2

Comment: Tim Peterson: The link in my comment should get you about to where you need to be. I'm unfamiliar with the EC2 administration environment, the only thing I can think of that might hold you up is copy+pasting the rsa key (if EC2 doesn't have a very GUI-y text editor available), and in that case you'll probably want to get more familiar with VI. If that's the case, this might help:

http://www.keyxl.com/aaab462/105/VIM-Text-Editor-keyboard-shortcuts.htm

Comment: hi Will, i've managed to clone the htdocs repo but unfortunately this directory was placed inside the directory, /var/www, i was targeting. I just wanted the contents of the htdocs directory and not the directory too (its now /var/www/htdocs), can you suggest how i might revise my cloning strategy (see updated question above) such that i just get /var/www/all-my-files. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `.` in the end:

```
git clone git@github.com:tim-peterson/htdocs.git .
```

---

In general, the syntax for `[git clone]` (excluding options) is

```
git clone <repository> [<directory>]
```

If you specify `<directory>`, it will be created relative to the current directory, and the repository will be created in it. If it is an absolute path, the repository will be created there.

If you omit `<directory>`, it is assumed to be the `basename` (last path element, excluding `.git` suffix) of the `<repository>`.

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-clone

Answer (score 1):

The repo is not a public repository ( or it doesn't even exist) from what I see here: https://github.com/tim-peterson

So if it is a private repo, you can't use the `git` protocol to clone it. You need to use https / ssh ( and in the latter case, setup the kets)

Comment: hi Manojlds, yes its a private repo, ok i'll do ssh, can you help me figure out how to setup the keys to do this?

Comment: hi Manojlds, i've managed to clone the htdocs repo but unfortunately this directory was placed inside the directory, /var/www, i was targeting. I just wanted the contents of the htdocs directory and not the directory too (its now /var/www/htdocs), can you suggest how i might revise my cloning strategy (see updated question above) such that i just get /var/www/all-my-files. thanks!

Comment: @timpeterson You can write the target path after `git clone` so for the current directory, just use `git clone URL .` and it will clone the repository into the current directory. Or you can simply move all files in that folder to a different place (make sure to also move the hidden `.git` folder!) and it will work too without having to clone again.